# Ruby multiple module class method name clash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mixins

```
module Filterable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    def filter
      where_state_id
    end

    def where_state_id
      puts "from filterable"
    end
  end
end

module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    def search
      where_state_id
    end

    def where_state_id
      puts "from Searchable"
    end
  end
end

class Deal
  include Filterable
  include Searchable
end
```

As per above
Deal.filter => # from Searchable

but my requirement is to print "from filterable"

I know about the method lookup steps, but how can I begin method lookup from the current module itself?

Comment: Does changing the include order solve your issue? Put include Searchable first..

Comment: then it will be an issue for the Searchable module. Basically, I need that the method lookup should begin with the current module

Comment: Take a look at `Deal.ancestors`. If you are familiar with how inheritance works you will understand why what you want is not possible with that code. Try composition instead.

Comment: Rename the method and save yourself a lot of headaches. It's possible to enclose it in another module that is not included and then call it from there (usually, might not be possible depending on what the method does), but just renaming it is way simpler.